# Происхождение слова "балбес"

Tags: этимология

Есть много слов, несущих в русском языке ругательный характер, но не до конца понятных по происхождению.
Например, слово "балбес". Что оно изначально значило?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ушаков дает такое пояснение: БАЛБЕС — от казах. balbas 'идол' (разг. бран., презрит.). От идола до болвана недалеко :-)
У Фасмера другая версия: балбес - из казах. bilbes (ср. татар., турецк. bilmas "он не знает"). Здесь *балбес* родственно слову *бельмес* (в выражении *ни бельмеса не понимает*).
В своем Историко-этимологическом словаре П.Я.Черных также придерживается версии тюркского происхождения этого слова со значением "незнающий, невежда".